# context.MyContext.SqlQuery() skips mapping logic from context's OnModelCreating()?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've just started using EntityFramework 6 and I'm still trying some scenarios out. I have overridden the OnModelCreating() method in my context class, and have some logic regarding some column name mappings to properties like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Ninja>().Property(x => x.DateOfBirth).HasColumnName("date_of_birth");
}
```

As you can see the property name is DateOfBirth, and the appropriate column in the DB is date_of_birth. Now when I'm adding/inserting new data in the DB this mapping works fine. And when I'm querying/retrieving data like this:

```
var ninja = context.Ninjas.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name.StartsWith("Kacy"));
```

It works fine.

But when I want to use a DB(postgre 10) function to retrieve the data:

```
private static void RetrieveDataWithStoredProc()
{
    using (var context = new NinjaContext())
    {
        context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
        var ninjas = context.Ninjas.SqlQuery("select * from get_old_ninjas()").ToList();
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'NinjaDomain.DataModel.Ninja'.
A member of the type, 'DateOfBirth', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

Which means it doesn't take into consideration the logic in the modelbuilder regarding the column name of the DateOfBirth property. 
If I add explicit mapping logic after the SqlQuery, it will work...

My question is why doesn't this method consider the logic already in place in the `OnModelCreating` method like all other cases do ?

Answer (score 0):

> why doesn't this method consider the logic already in place in the OnModelCreating method like all other cases do ?

That is a limitation in EF6.  EF Core respects your column mappings when loading from raw SQL queries:

> The column names in the result set must match the column names that
>   properties are mapped to. Note this is different from EF6 where
>   property/column mapping was ignored for raw SQL queries and result set
>   column names had to match the property names.

[Raw SQL Queries (EF Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)